# Setup multiple django gunicorn instances with nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Got one django site running with gunicorn & nginx need to setup another site also with the same. Nginx settings is straight forward, how to rework below to add another site `/home/ubuntu/webapps/uganda_buzz/`

relevant settings are `/etc/init/gunicorn.conf`

```
description "Gunicorn application server handling all projects"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
setuid user
setgid www-data
chdir /home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz

exec /home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application
```

and `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/webapps/djangoenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/webapps/kenyabuzz/kb.sock kb.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. You already have the files for your current project, why can't you do the same for the second one?

Comment: so I just create duplicate links for `ExecStart` , `WorkingDirectory` , `chdir` and `exec` for the other django application with their path, feels like a hack and likely to crash?

Comment: Why? Why is it a hack and why would it crash?

Comment: It's not documented and the art of coding is knowing an error is on the way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158984/nginx-two-instances-not-working-only-one-site-running

Comment: I don't understand what you expect to be documented. You have some files that handle one site; you need to create some more files to handle the other site. Although I don't understand why you have configs for both upstart and systemd; your server will only use one of those systems.

Comment: Can I run multiple Django server using systemd gunicorn?

Answer (score 0):

Try  [How To Set Up Nginx Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

or [Configuring multiple domains and subdomains. DNS & Nginx issues abound!](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/configuring-multiple-domains-and-subdomains-dns-nginx-issues-abound)