# How to run multiple Django App Gunicorn systemd?

Tags: django, server, gunicorn, systemd

I have two `django projects` running on different ports in same `ec2 instance`, One I have configured with gunicorn system as follows by creating `gunicorn.service` file at `/etc/systemd/system/` which is working awesome if I run the command `systemctl start gunicorn`. Now I want to run another proect, how can I configure it, currently I am running that using gunicorn command `/usr/local/bin/gunicorn --graceful-timeout 30 --bind 0.0.0.0:8690 projectFile.wsgi:application --daemon`, Can I add same in `gunicorn.service` itself. How do I configure multiple projects in `gunicorn systemd`?

gunicron.service file -

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target


[Service]
PIDFile=/tmp/gunicorn.pid
LogFile=/tmp/lgunicorn.log
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/website/UniservedWebsite

ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --graceful-timeout 30 --bind 0.0.0.0:8134 UniservedWebsite.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What are you using as server engine, Nginx, Apache?

Comment: @campovski, Nuthing I am running both projects individually. Neither using nginx nor Apache.Only Gunicorn

Comment: If you run each project separately on different ports, do they work? What I mean is that if you run project 1 on port 8080 it works and if you then stop it and run project 2 on port 8081, it works too?

Comment: Obviously, And if I run both projects at time on different ports , why do you think it will not work?

Comment: As I know it and I did some googling now, people think that it cannot work or it is hard to accomplish it. The easiest way it would be to install Nginx and set up proxy_pass. That's what I know how to do. Besides, Nginx is really lightweight.

Comment: Nginx will only redirect any url at my server , And for that my server needs to be working fwhich I am doing via gunicorn, Now with gunicorn I want to start two projects at a time, How to do it , Its query?

Comment: Oh, I see. I understood it that if you try to run both at the same time, you can only access one, not both of them. I didn't realize that you actually cannot run both. Check [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156646/setup-multiple-django-gunicorn-instances-with-nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156646/setup-multiple-django-gunicorn-instances-with-nginx), the answer is in answers to the question. You need not worry about Nginx stuff there, just Gunicorn :) I think that that will answer it!

Comment: I have accomplish it by creating two `.service` file and start it separately.

Comment: Good job, see that link helped! Glad you made it :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create two `.service` file, and start them separately...